# ActiveRecord querying stops working when adding pagination | Rails 5 |

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pagination

I am new to RoR and I'm following a course online. I've implemented ActiveRecord querying as well as will_paginate gem and both work fine separatedly.

However, after I've added pagination, the query search breaks and gives me the following error:

**NoMethodError in Products#index
undefined method `total_pages' for #**

```
Extracted source (around line #7):

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="pages">
     <%= will_paginate @products %>
</div>

  <div class="row">
```

---

***Gemfile***

```
gem 'will_paginate'
```

---

***products_controller.rb***

```
def index
  if params[:q]
    search_term = params[:q]
    if (Rails.env == "production")
      @products = Product.where("name ilike ?", "%#{search_term}%")
    else
      @products = Product.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search_term}%")
    end
  else
    @products = Product.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
  end
end
```

---

```
 private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end
```

---

***application.html.erb***

```
<li class="nav-search">
  <%= form_tag("/products", method: "get") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Go!", class: 'button-s') %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because, when `params[:q]` is present, pagination is not turned on.
I'd do something along these lines:

```
def index
  @products = find_products.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
end

private

def find_products
  if params[:q]
    search_term = params[:q]
    if (Rails.env == "production")
      Product.where("name ilike ?", "%#{search_term}%")
    else
      Product.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search_term}%")
    end
  else
    Product.all
  end
end
```

Though, the `if (Rails.env == "production")` looks a bit fishy :)

Comment: Thank you for the snippet. Code looks cleaner this way than my original correction :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you haven't added the `paginate` call to the `@products = ...` assignments that get called when there is a search term.  This call to paginate is what adds the `total_pages` method to the collection, otherwise you're just dealing with a normal (ie. unpaginated) ActiveRecord collection.